# Where to save user uploaded images in CodeIgniter?

Tags: database, image, codeigniter

What I want to do is let a user save an image and when they're accessing their accounts I want the image to display.

1. What I'm currently doing is I'm saving the images in **public** folder
2. Store the path to the database
   Path: css\img\myPic.jpg
3. Display the image
   <img class="border" src='esc($empInfo['img'])' style="height: 200px; width: 200px">

But since this is a public folder I can't save personal pictures in this folder

I also tried saving the path to writable\uploads\myPic.jpg but no luck

Comment: removed <?= ?> in img tag. because it displays img with an empty src

Comment: its safe to upload your images in public/uploads/ folder you just have to add blank index.htm so that it will not display/list the images from that path also use random string for your uploaded image filename.

Answer (score 0):

As of the the moment. the solution that I got is "copying" the file(in my case it is an image file)from writable/uploads to public using Publish Library.

```
    $publisher = new Publisher(WRITEPATH . 'uploads', FCPATH. 'img/');
    $publisher->addPaths([
        'img/myPic.jpg',
    ]);
    $publisher->copy(true); // `true` to enable overwrite
```

- Source Path: WRITEPATH . 'uploads'
- Destination Path: FCPATH. 'img/'
- Source File: img/myPic.jpg

Now you can ref the image in img tags.

Next step should be replacing/deleting the image after use, because this is not gonna be different when you upload the image at public folder. Will try to update if I found a solution

Source: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/publisher.html

PS. Feel free to correct me :) I am also new to web developing in general

Part2: I added this to my function. what it does is after copying the image to the public folder I then rename to 'myPic.jpg'. this will solve my previous problem "replacing/deleting the image after use".

```
 $renameFile = rename(FCPATH. 'img/'.$fileName, FCPATH . 'img/'. 'myPic.jpg');
    if($renameFile){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a manual or a concept , you can also try this:

1. You must have some folder where you store all personal images
2. When user needs it, copy the file into Public folder with a random generated 32 character name (GUID type) but with the original extension.
3. Then feed it to the user in the view.
4. Once displayed after the view is called you can delete the image from that folder.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for sharing this. I also commented my solution thought it might help someone in the future. Do you have anything to add to my code below ?

Comment: this is how my image names look like: https://www.guidgen.com/. I also maintain the ones used in a table so I can delete them later. For example when user session is finished all images cached for the user are deleted. Other than that it looks pretty close to what I'm using